# separator value from fact variable in ansible

Tags: ansible, template

I get ssh connection from fact variable in fact.

my code in template (get-ip.j2):

`nod= {{ ansible_env.SSH_CONNECTION }}`

my output is :

`nod= 192.168.231.115 55414 192.168.231.91 22`

Now, how can I separator `192.168.231.91` from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting into the answer, I recommend using stackoverflow for Ansible/Jinja2 questions. There's a lot of questions already answered there.

Now, as for your question: Split the string on space and then extract the third element:

```
{{ansible_env.SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2]}}
```